# zf2: Zend Client and cUrl not working

Tags: zend-framework2

```
$adapter = new \Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl();

    $client = new \Zend\Http\Client($url);
    $client->setAdapter($adapter);
    $client->setMethod('POST');
    $adapter->setOptions(array(
        'curloptions' => array(
                            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
            CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
            CURLOPT_USERPWD => "username:password",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,

        )
    ));
  $client->send();
```

The above snipped with what i'm using and i'm following the docs here http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.http.client.adapters.html

The problem is that when i do my own curl function call it works fine and i get a valid response. but when i use the zend convention i keep getting a 401- unauthorized.  The curl options that im using are the same for both methods.

any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember having problems with that example so I used another, this works for me:

```
$request = new Request();
$request->setUri($url);
$request->setMethod('POST');

$client = new Client();
$adapter = new \Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl();
$client->setAdapter($adapter);

$adapter->setOptions(array(
    'curloptions' => array(
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => "username:password",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
    )
));

$response = $client->dispatch($request);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and CURLOPT_POST are blocked by the invalidOverwritableCurlOptions array in Curl.php, what you want to do is set your parameters on the Client instead.

Using the setParameterPost method in Zend/Http/Client like so:

```
    use Zend\Http\Client;
    use Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl;

    //some post params
    $postParams = array('per_page' => 25);

    $adapter = new Curl();
    // -- add your curl options here (excluding CURLOPT_POST and CURLOP_POSTFIELDS --

    $client = new Client('https://example.com/somePage');
    $client->setAdapter($adapter);
    $client->setMethod('POST');
    $client->setParameterPost($postParams);
    $response = $client->send($client->getRequest());

    //output the response
    echo $response->getBody()."<br/>";
```

You don't even need to make a Request object as the Client class will make one anyway.  In the above code I just retrieve the one that Client creates using the getRequest method and then pass it to the send method.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Doesn't allow overwriting the option CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

You need to figure out how to overwrite that.

Removing this option from invalidOverwritableCurlOptions in curl.php of Zend library will solve your problem. But you need to find the way that doesn't interfere with the library.